# How can I see the class proxy code in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I want to see what code is generated on the fly by Transactional annotation in Spring. How can i do this?
If this is impossible or difficult to do, then please tell me what code Spring inserts into the methods annotated with Transactional annotation. I know that using EntityManager in transactions should be used `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();` and `entityManager.getTransaction().commit();`. But how does it work in a multi-threaded environment, when many threads access the same EntityManager and call `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();`? If a transaction has been opened, an exception will be thrown. Therefore, if Spring inserts exactly this code with transactions into methods, how does it work in a multithreaded environment?

Answer (score 1):

The proxy codes are not generated. It is actually some static codes that implement  `InvocationHandler`. See [this](https://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jdk-dynamic-proxies) for a hello world example for how does it work.

In term of Spring AOP , the implementation of `InvocationHandler` is `JdkDynamicAopProxy` which will somehow invokes `TransactionInterceptor` for `@Transactional`.

So the entry point is to look at `TransactionInterceptor#invoke(MethodInvocation)` which are the codes execute around a `@Transactional` method.